# Bounty on my question

Tags: support, specific-question

I have put a 50 point bounty on my question [Are there any passages in Early Christian literature that discuss angels and pagans?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/95730/are-there-any-passages-in-early-christian-literature-that-discuss-angels-and-pag) 3 days ago. There are 4 more days before the bounty expires. However, I have not yet received an answer there. I cannot understand why everyone is getting so late to answer my question during the bounty period.

Comment: I doubt there is much interest in the technical details regarding the providences of pagans. This is a Christianity site and the focus is on comparative Chrsitianity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a bounty is no guarantee of getting more answers. Maybe no one is interested in the question or maybe no one knows enough to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Northern Hemisphere Summers on Christianity.SE are notoriously low-key, the only questions that get a lot of traction on the site are usually the semi-controversial ones and 50 points of potential bounty points might not be sufficient draw for a question about this.

Are you basically looking for Early Christian references to the modern doctrines regarding Guardian Angels?

Comment: I am looking for Early Christian references to the modern doctrines regarding Guardian Angels.